# Why is reducer failing to update the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

It looks to me like I have my component, action creator, and reducer all set up correctly, but for some reason, my store isn't being updated when I move the slider.

This is my App.js file sans imports

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 100,
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
    console.log(value)
    this.props.dispatch(PriceFilter(value))
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)

    return (
      <div style={styles.root}>
        <Slider
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { price: state.reducers }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

My action is super simple

```
export const PriceFilter = (price) => ({
    type: 'PRICE_FILTER',
    price: price
})
```

My reducer is also very basic:

```
const initialState = {
    price: 10000
}

const priceReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'PRICE_FILTER':
            return {
                ...state,
                price: action.price
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default priceReducer
```

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did yiu try to add console.log in action creator and reducer?

Comment: Yes, and it's returning the correct value...which narrows it down. The weird thing is the value is being returned as undefined. Even though I can see it when I console it.

Comment: Please add the console.log calls to the code that you have posted and indicate where the value is printed and where it is undefined.

Comment: figured it out, it was in my mapStateToProps which should have been this. const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { price: state.price }
}

Answer (score 1):

check whether your `redux` state is coming or not by `console`. i think if you haven't used `combineReducers` method in redux than your redux store comes by `state` only.

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state) // check redux store
  return { price: state.reducers }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change mapStateToProps to this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return { price: state.price }
}
```